# Here Maps — how to create an empty Polyline?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to create an empty Polyline:

```
let line = new window.H.geo.LineString();
let strip = new window.H.geo.Strip();

console.log(line);
console.log(strip);

console.log(new window.H.map.Polyline(strip)); // throws an error
console.log(new window.H.map.Polyline(line)); // throws an error
```

but both variants throws an error:

`InvalidArgumentError: H.map.Polyline#setGeometry (Argument #0)`

UPD1:

Even if i first insert a Point in the LineString still got the same error:

```
let point = new window.H.geo.Point(55.755814, 37.617635, 0);

console.log(point);

line.pushPoint(point);

console.log(new window.H.map.Polyline(line)); // throws an error
```

UPD2:

Oh, i got it — i MUST insert at least 2 points in LineString or Strip first and only then i'm allowed to create a polyline.

UPD3:

Also, LineString is the same as Strip.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the updated post, there are at least 2 points required for creating a polyline using H.geo.Strip(Deprecated) or H.geo.LineString.